# Payments to App Store

Tags: mac-appstore

Suppose I want to find (for tax purposes) the amounts of all payments I made to the App store during 2014.  In the App Store application, I did not find this information in "Purchases" nor in "View My Account".

Is there something easier than finding the dates of my purchases (under "Purchases"), then looking for that date in my credit card statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open iTunes on your Mac or PC.
2. Click iTunes Store.
3. Click Sign In.
4. Enter your Apple ID and password.
5. Click your Apple ID and select Account Info from the drop-down menu.
6. Next to Purchase History, click See All.

   - It might take a moment for your Purchase History to appear.
7. To see the details for a purchase, click the arrow to the left of the order date. Your most recent purchases are first.

   - You'll see the date, time, and web order number in the top-right corner. If you don't recognize a purchase, see if it's one of these types of charges.

[Source](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204088)

Comment: So you are tilling me that I look in the iTunes store to find the OS X apps that I bought?

Comment: All purchases from the iTunes store should be in one place.

Comment: OK, I see it works.  "Apps" shows me only iOS apps, but "Purchase History" shows those and OS X apps along with movies and music.